# Extract Month from partial date in R

Tags: r, string, date, gsub

I have a partial date string

```
partial <- "UN-Jan-2022"
```

My desired output

```
> parital
  Jan
```

I'm trying to do this by using gsub, I can remove "UN-" or -"2022" but not sure how to remove both in one gsub

```
gsub("UN-", "", partial)
Jan-2022
gsub("-2022", "", partial)
UN-Jan
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another `gsub` option which extracts everything between both "-" like this:

```r
partial <- "UN-Jan-2022"
gsub(".*-(.*)\\-.*", "\\1", partial)
#> [1] "Jan"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: A little inquiry @Quinten why escape the second `-`? Why not just `gsub(".*-(.*)-(.*)", "\\1", partial)`

Answer (score 1):

We could convert to `Date` format and then use `format`

```
format(as.Date(paste0(partial, '-01'), 'UN-%b-%Y-%d'), '%b')
[1] "Jan"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, based on `stringr::str_match` and regex capture groups:

```r
stringr::str_match(partial, ".*-(.*)-.*")[2]

#> [1] "Jan"
```